# Second google account never shows up

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I want to add a Google account to use as the primary (paying) account in Google Play.

I have tried to add the account in the Google Play app or in settings under Accounts and sync. I get no error, but after the sign in process, the account is never listed.

I am using two step verification. I am running Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (build number IMM76D.XWLPY).

Comment: try rebooting the device and adding the account again. Also if that doesn't help use mobile data to add it.

Comment: I tried many times. Eventually it worked. Unfortunately I don't really understand why. What was also irritating was that when I succeeded it insisted on starting to sync contacts/mail/calendar, so I had to turn those off manually as fast as I could